# RestAssured how to access query parameter while mid-statement?

Tags: java, rest, functional-programming, rest-assured

I'm writing tests against an API that hmacsha1 hashes the entire get request query string using a secret key and sends it in the header. So I need to compute for this value, set it in the header, before executing the test. like this:

```
expect()
        .statusCode(200)
.given()
        .parameter("key", "abc")
        .parameter("param2", "def")
        .header("Authorization",hmacsha1(queryString,"secretKey"))
.when()
        .get("/endpoint");
```

Is there a way I can access the current query string at the "queryString" location? basically it should give me "key=abc&param2=def" so I can hash it in-place.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a [filter](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Filters) and hash the query params before the request is sent to the server?